# Why would a question be flagged for a reopen if it has already been answered?

Tags: discussion

Got a reopen vote for this question: [how to add html in ordered item section in admin panel?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111054/how-to-add-html-in-ordered-item-section-in-admin-panel)

If you check the revision, the content has changed quite a lot: https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/111054/revisions

But this question has already been answered and the answer has been approved by the OP, why would this question be flagged for a reopen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questions that are closed and edited are automatically marked for reopening.
So if a user edits his own question that will appear in the reopen votes queue even if the the question is already answered and the answer is accepted.

Comment: Thanks for that